# Emit data to all clients on a Google Web App

Tags: sockets, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a Google Apps Script bound to a Google Sheet, and have published that as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). It is restricted to a certain Google Workspace. That Google Sheet is kind of an improvised database for that web app and changes over time. I would like to send the updated data to all clients once the Google sheet gets changed. Is that possible? I don't need a [trigger for the edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), since I know in the script when I add new data, so this is the time to send the new data.

Basically the same question can be formulated as follows: We know that we can execute a server-side function from the client with [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run), but is it also possible to execute a client-side function from the server i.e. the apps script?

My current workaround is a client-side `setInterval` which checks for server-side updates (and fetches them using [successHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))) every 30 seconds or so. It works, but is not optimal.

Comment: It's not possible to execute a client side function from the server unless it has been first initiated by the client and it's responding with a callback.  Polling is your only option I think.

Comment: Your clients could access the webapp and get the data themselves as long as they meet the requirements of your deployment.

Comment: Back in the day you could have pulled this off using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) but that service has been deprecated and removed in favor of FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging). FCM leverages the web Push API which requires Service Workers. Unfortunately, GAS Web Apps do not currently support service workers. So like @Cooper has stated you have to fall back on a "pull" model where you periodically poll the database for changes.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So this "polling" is the workaround I described in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark this one as answered. Cooper writes in the comments:

"It's not possible to execute a client side function from the server unless it has been first initiated by the client and it's responding with a callback. Polling is your only option I think."